# No sound except system sounds 16.04

Tags: 16.04

It worked fine until I connected to TV via HDMI. It worked then on tv but now there's no sound.

No sound in rhythmbox, chrome, or firefox.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: yes. the sound went out over a weeek ago and I've rebooted multiple times since then

Comment: run `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` to make sure it is still recognizing your sound card/driver

Comment: If the above command outputs your sounds card, then check you sounds settings to make sure the output devices isn't still set to HDMI. Through the GUI you can do that by clicking sounds settings when adjusting your volume from the drop down menu. Through terminal you can view available output devices by running `pacmd list-sinks`

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue on ubuntu 18.04. In sound settings GUI,  "Speaker - Built-in Audio" is selected but there no sound coming from speakers except the system sounds.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the issue is with the pulseaudio configuration files. They are somehow messed up.

I had the same problem with my linux Ubuntu 18 and I searched online for a long time until I found the answer.

The easiest and most effective solution is that you delete all the configuration files for pulse (pulseaudio) and then restart pulseaudio.

type the following code in the terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse*
pulseaudio -k
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That did the trick for me on Fedora. No idea what caused it to break, happened after I tried to switch from my bt speaker to bt headphones.

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, you are the soul saver, m8 :) Thank you

Comment: Worked also on 20.04, many thanks

Comment: Worked in 21.10.